# Use google charts to make chart with user input

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

```
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
<form method="post" action="#" id="formvalue" onekeyup="drawChart()"> 
<input type="number" id="x" value=2>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts
/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
var ask=document.getElementById('x');

var a=90;

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
['Work',     11],
['Eat',      2],
['Commute',  2],
['Watch TV', 2],
['Sleep',    ask]
]);

var options = {
title: 'My Daily Activities'
};

var chart = new   
google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

the input given by the user is not well stored in the variable ask by the getElementById('x') . Please help!!
I wanted to use it in one of the parameters of the chart.
['Sleep',ask]
if there is anyother way to make a chart on the basis of user input ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code has an error which is the reason that it is not able to get the value of the variable `ask`. The assignment to this variable should be `document.getElementById('x').value` to retrieve the value from the input field/box.

I think you are on the right track, if you want to create a chart on the basis of user input. You would have seperate input fields for each Task hours and the form can be submitted through the use of an Submit button which calls the `drawChart()` function to redraw the graph OR even the current method that you are using to submit the form.

Something like this for users who require a submit button:

```
<form action="">
   Hours Worked:<br>
   <input type="number" name="work"><br>
   Hours Slept:<br>
   <input type="number" name="sleep"><br><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="drawChart()">
</form>
```

The same method would be used to retrieve the values from the input form as mentioned above.

You may get an error in your console.log as before page load there may not be values defined in the input form. To stop this either remove `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);` or perform a validation of your input values, so the graph is not drawn when input fields are empty or you can use a default value when the input fields are empty.

More information on form validation and example code is available [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp).

Comment: thank you very much for your answer..  but there is a slight problem as i can access the value into ask which i can check by using alert(ask); but the problem is it does not goes as in the var data..?would u mind me explaining that!! instead if i simply use var a =90 and put in the place of ask, its going well but not ask??

Comment: It should work fine as it works for my dummy example. Could you provide a JSFiddle Editor Link? Or if you have not fixed your syntax error for your form `onekeyup="drawChart()!` to `onkeyup="drawChart()"`, then that may be the issue.

Comment: This should fix your problem, but if your using large data sets then this current method of input forms is not advisable. Better solutions would using a .csv file or data from a database. [https://jsfiddle.net/76bxkhqd/](https://jsfiddle.net/76bxkhqd/)

Comment: oh u got a nice method ... !!  thanks for the help :)